# Armbian IPv6 autoconfiguration

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6

I have armbian on nanoPI where IPv6 autoconfiguration does not work as I expect it to. There is another computer on the network, which has IPv6 tunnel configured and radvd installed to advertise IPv6 autoconfiguration. It works fine on my laptop, where IPv6 is autoconfigured.

nanoPi with armbian is used for IPv4 wireguard tunnel, caching DNS and IPv4 DHCP. That all works fine, and I do not want to mess it up. However, I also want it to work with IPv6. I have found out in logs, that DNS tries to make IPv6 connections and reports "network unreachable".

The problem is, I think, in default IPv6 gateway. I first thought it has something to do with kernel options `net.ipv6.conf.*.accept_ra` and `net.ipv6.conf.*.forwarding`. Then I stopped tweaking these options, and I still get these strange results. The following commands show what happens:

```
root@hostname:/home/nobody# systemctl restart networking; sleep 5; ip -6 route; echo --------------; sleep 30; ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:470:dead:beef::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 expires 86398sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::e578:dc2a:5850:1a23 dev eth0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1798sec hoplimit 64 pref medium
-------------
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:470:dead:beef::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 expires 86368sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
```

As it can be seen from the output, there is a default gateway and then it goes away. I do not know what deletes the gateway shortly after the network restart. As can be observed, 5 seconds after restart there is a default gateway, but 30 seconds after restart is is no more there.

How should I setup the right IPv6 options so that eth0 will correctly setup and keep IPv6 routing. IPv6 address is assigned. In `/etc/network/interfaces`, IPv6 for eth0 is very simple:

```
iface eth0 inet6 auto
```

Network addresses for `eth0` are:

```
root@hostname:/home/nobody# /sbin/ifconfig 
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.3  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 2001:470:dead:beef:9839:10ff:fe2c:bc8b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 fe80::9839:10ff:fe2c:bc8b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 9a:39:10:2c:bc:8b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 99643  bytes 19933415 (19.9 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 70276  bytes 15165013 (15.1 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 36
```

---

These are additional info answering questions in comment.

In `/etc/sysctl.conf`, I only have one line related to `net.ipv6.conf`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

I tried also with forwarding disabled. The result was the same.

`radvd` settings `/etc/radvd.conf` on the gateway are:

```
interface eth0
{
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    AdvLinkMTU 1480;
    prefix 2001:470:dead:beef::/64
    {
        AdvOnLink on;
        AdvAutonomous on;
    };
};
```

`rdisc6 eth0` on nanoPI armbian shows:

```
nobody@hostname:~$ rdisc6 eth0
Soliciting ff02::2 (ff02::2) on eth0...

Hop limit                 :           64 (      0x40)
Stateful address conf.    :           No
Stateful other conf.      :           No
Mobile home agent         :           No
Router preference         :       medium
Neighbor discovery proxy  :           No
Router lifetime           :         1800 (0x00000708) seconds
Reachable time            :  unspecified (0x00000000)
Retransmit time           :  unspecified (0x00000000)
 Prefix                   : 2001:470:dead:beef::/64
  On-link                 :          Yes
  Autonomous address conf.:          Yes
  Valid time              :        86400 (0x00015180) seconds
  Pref. time              :        14400 (0x00003840) seconds
 Source link-layer address: 02:BA:01:E2:BB:0A
 from fe80::e578:dc2a:5850:1a23
```

Network configuration on the gateway is:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2001:470:dead:beaf:ba:1ff:fee2:bb0a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::e578:dc2a:5850:1a23  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2001:470:dead:beef:d80:ee60:c02c:fd7b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:470:dead:beef:d335:85e2:7581:a8bb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:470:dead:beef:a4cd:3f7c:831e:5741  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:470:dead:beef:4de7:a7f9:b4f1:276f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:470:dead:beef:579c:d1ec:a9e4:956e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 02:ba:01:e2:bb:0a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1878860  bytes 2020311395 (2.0 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1706952  bytes 1964158895 (1.9 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 42  

he-ipv6: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1480
        inet6 2001:470:deaf:beef::2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::c0a8:4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        sit  txqueuelen 1000  (IPv6-in-IPv4)
        RX packets 1419735  bytes 1890050581 (1.8 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 258256  bytes 40728885 (40.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: What are your _current_ settings of `net.ipv6.conf`? Does the default gateway address belong to the correct device (i.e. your real IPv6 gateway)? What are your radvd settings on the gateway; what does `rdisc6 eth0` show?

Comment: @user1686 The information you asked for is added to the question.